# Error in Flutter code- Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, authentication

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const RunMyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
  ));
}

class RunMyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RunMyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(children: const <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a phone number',
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  hintText: 'Enter Password',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NextPage()));
            },
            child: const Text('Home Page')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Next Page'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Welcome'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting error - "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.at  [21:9]"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code :
You added  multiple childs to `Center` widgte  You should wrap to `Column` widget. Following is the correct code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const RunMyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
  ));
}

class RunMyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RunMyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
       child : 
        Column(
        
           children: [
              Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(children: const <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a phone number',
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  hintText: 'Enter Password',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
       ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NextPage()));
            },
            child: const Text('Home Page')),
           ],
        ),
        
       
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Next Page'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Welcome'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```